# Using TimerTask in Android

Tags: java, android, final, timertask

I'm trying to make a method that simply changes a boolean to false after a certain amount of time. So far I have:

`public void changeBool(int timeoutMillis, boolean toTurnFalse){
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toTurnFalse = false;
        }
    };
    mTimer.schedule(tt, timeoutMillis);
}`

But I'm getting an error on the line: `toTurnFalse = false;` asking me to change it to a `final` variable but I don't want to do this and it also produces a different error itself. How do I avoid the `final` variable problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead what you should do is you have the state variable as a global member inside of your Activity class and then have a Handler message that your TimerTask dispatches via the handler to your Activity and updates the state of the variable.

Also another possibility if you're timing for a short period of time, you could just dispatch a delayed message via a Handler, wouldn't need a TimerTask for that.

Answer (score 0):

try to write `boolean tuTurnFalse = false`instead of `tuTurnFalse = false`

Comment: By using `toTurnFalse` I'm trying to use the boolean that was passed into the method. Doing this change would just make a new boolean and set it to false.